# py.test 2.3.5: generative tests that use fixtures?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Is it possible to pass fixtures to pytest generative tests?

```
import py.test

@py.test.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture():
    return True

def test_1(fixture):
    def checker(datum):
        assert datum == fixture
    for i in [True, True, True]:
        # Does not work.
        yield checker, i
        # Does work.
        #checker(i)
```

The above code produces

```
>       for i, x in enumerate(self.obj()):
            name, call, args = self.getcallargs(x)
E           TypeError: test_1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

We use py.test 2.3.5 from Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know exactly what `yield` inside test definition suppose to do.

There is `yield` in fixtures [Fixture functions using “yield” / context manager integration](http://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html) that works not as one expects at first.

If you want to iterate the same test over a sequence of fixtures you probably need [Parametrizing a fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-a-fixture)

Comment: It was supposed to generate a number of tests for a set of parameters.  Somehow I was using it because I have seen it in a few blog posts, but apparently this approach is deprecated in favor of `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

Comment: "Fixtured functions using 'yield' / context manager integration" and "Parameterizing a fixuture" links are broken.